# Redmine rmagick is not available

Tags: imagemagick, redmine, rmagick

I installed Redmine on Ubuntu 14 with RMagick and ImageMagick, but in "Administration - Information", I still see that they are unavailable - red.

When I tried to make a pdf file, it also doesn't put the attachments into the pdf file.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running apache, did you have env PATH set to it. the binary should be accessible in one of path entries

PATH=/bin:/...